# Is calorific deficit sufficient to reduce body fat percentage, or do dietary details play a part?

Tags: weight-loss, diet, body-fat, paleo-diet

My goal is to (a) lose weight, and (b) reduce body fat percentage in order to see muscle definition.

I'm making good progress with losing weight by following a diet that most closely resembles the 4-hour-body diet, but is also similar to paleo/primal diets in that I'm getting a lot of calories from protein and saturated fats and not many from sugar or "white carbs".

Question: I'm losing about 1lb/week of weight so I'm clearly operating at a reasonable calorific deficit. Does the TYPE of food I'm eating affect the speed at which body fat percentage reduces, or are calories the only factor?

Comment: The data is pretty indeterminate on specific dietary choices and their effect on weight loss, in part because most people marketing these diets tend to omit things such as what they're comparing their method against, total caloric intake, and exercise, but the actual scientific studies with properly designed methodology keep showing that calories are what matter for weight loss, and a moderate amount of exercise allows humans to consume just about anything and get sufficient nutrition from it. It's part of how we evolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of overall weight loss, indeed it does not matter what you eat as long as you are operating on a deficit. Your body operates on a simple physical principle.

*However*: running on a deficit with low-fiber, highly-metabolizing foods (such as sugar), will make your weight loss pure torture. You want to feel satiated, have long lasting energy, and maintain muscle definition. Thus, you want to go for a diet full of fiber, healthy fats (from fish, for example), medium-to-high protein, and plenty of vegetables.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not talking about overall weight loss though: it's body fat percentage I'm concerned about. Perhaps "reducing body fat percentage" is exactly the same thing as "overall weight loss"? I've been assuming that  what I need to do is lose fat but retain muscle if possible, and perhaps diet plays a part in that. What do you think?

Comment: Yes it's possible (or possible to within marginal muscle loss). However, this is only possible via muscle activation. If you are on caloric deficit, no matter what you eat, if you're not putting your muscles into work your body will eat them away because, essentially, your body counts them as using unnecessary calories. So you need to perform high-weight, low rep (stress your body out) gym sessions for no more than 30-45 minutes, several times a week. This will ensure you're maintaining muscle.

Comment: Also, make sure you supplement your body with sufficient protein, usually 0.8g to 1g per pound of lean body weight is sufficient.